# AspxGridVIew : How to get visiblerowsonpage count on server side?

Tags: c#, count, devexpress, rows, aspxgridview

How can I get the count of the visible rows on the current page in the gridview on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instructions from [ASPxGridView-Traversing Rows](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument5299) help topic to process the required ASPxGridView rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code

```
int rowCount = myGridView.ChildRows.Count(row => row.IsVisible);
```

Comment: hmmm it works in a normal grid but the one i am using (devexpress aspxgridview) is kind of special and unfortunately doesn't recognize childRows.Count(condition)